# Add multiple products to collection with one API call

Tags: shopify

was wondering if the Shopify API allows for multiple products to be added to a custom collection in one single call?
I've already managed to have one product only per call added to a custom collection via PHP. However I can't get multiple products added at once.

Below is a sample of the call I'm making to "/admin/collects.json"

```
$producs_array = array(
        "collect"=>array(
            "product_id"=>123456789,
            "product_id"=>123456789,
            "product_id"=>123456789,
        "collection_id"=> "123456789")
    );
```

Anyone managed to do this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can PUT to an existing collection. See https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customcollection#update

Comment: Hi I'm just going through this now. The documentation mentions "_Use product_id for products being added to the collection, and id for products that were already in the collection_" would the "id" map to a collect id or a product id? Thanks

Comment: The id is the existing collect id. Basically to update a collection you [load the collects](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/collect#index) for a target collection, sort out your changes and the PUT the collection with the collects members having either a collect id to preserve an existing product membership or a product product_id to add a product to the collection.